# Python UnicodeEncodeError in ElementTree.parse()

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, encoding, python-requests, elementtree

I am writing a python interface to an API.  The interface must use python 2.7.x, using python 3.x is not possible.

The API is called through a `requests` request.  In the particular case I'm having a problem with, I receive an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xdf' in position 24037: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried several progressively less naive approaches to handle this.  All fail.

1.

`tree = ElementTree().parse( StringIO(apiResult.body) )`

2.

```
parser = XMLParser(encoding="UTF-8")
tree = ElementTree().parse( StringIO(apiResult.body), parser=parser )
```

3.

```
parser = XMLParser(encoding="ISO-8859-1")
tree = ElementTree().parse( StringIO(apiResult.body), parser=parser )
```

All fail with the error message shown above.  In all cases `apiResult.body` is a string.  My question is why is the ascii codec being invoked in cases 2 and 3, when I'm explicitly using a parser with an encoding other than ascii?

And of course, how may I fix this?

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem?

Comment: Please, if possible, share 1. How do you receive that `apiResult.body` data on the `requests` level 2. The nature/content of `apiResult.body` itself

Answer (score 1):

It's a python API.  The problem is that the server is returning unicode, because the API is not putting `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` in the header.  I can encode the body in UTF-8 after it is received and then it works.  Or maybe I can fix the API to do it.